# Removing and Adding element in array in React Freezes Browser

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, lodash

**I'm Using reactjs and using lodash function to add and remove array elements but whenever i add or remove array browser freezes or slowdown for a bit.**

**take a look at** app: https://coindb.netlify.com
**Github Repo**: https://github.com/solankivj94/hexteria

I change keys on map of array from index keys to unique key. but the result is same

```
addCoin = (key) => {
    let maxFav = 6;
    let favorites = [ ...this.state.fav ];

    if (favorites.length < maxFav && !_.includes(this.state.fav, key)) {
        favorites.push(key);
        this.setState({ fav: favorites });
    }
    // console.log(_.includes(this.state.fav, key));
};

removeCoin = (key) => {
    let favorites = [ ...this.state.fav ];
    this.setState({ fav: _.pull(favorites, key) });
    // console.log('REmove coiin');
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In `src/Components/Setting/CoinTile.js`

Change this

```
<Tile onClick={clickCoinHandler(props.topSection, props.coinKey, props.addCoin, props.removeCoin)}>
```

To This

```
<Tile onClick={()=>{clickCoinHandler(props.topSection, props.coinKey, props.addCoin, props.removeCoin)}}>
```

Also change the `clickCoinHandler` function

```
const clickCoinHandler = (topSection, coinKey, addCoin, removeCoin) => {
    return topSection ? removeCoin(coinKey) : addCoin(coinKey);
};
```

Let me know if that works

Comment: its still lagging.